# Image.Write to FTP corrupted?

Tags: c#, ftp

I've had this code running and it's been running perfectly fine - until a few weeks back when it decided it doesn't want to work.

I'm not sure exactly why it's not working.

A selected image is resized and then uploaded to the server. However, the application only uploads 4.380kb of the file - regardless what image I select.
This is regardless of what directory I save it in.

The FTP account definitely has permissions and can upload other files without issue. Thus I think something in the code for uploading the image must be the problem?

UploadImage

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadLocation);
FileInfo toUpload = new FileInfo(fileToUpload);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();           

Image image = Image.FromFile(fileToUpload);
image = Tools.ScaleImage(image, 500, 360);
image.Save(ftpStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
image.Save(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\image.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Thinking it could be something to do with my resize code, I saved a copy of the file to the desktop - the file saved perfectly and is saved as expected.

However, here is the code as shown:

ScaleImage

```
public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

    var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
    Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    return newImage;
}
```

As I say, using exactly the same FTP credentials into the same folder, I am able to use ftp stream to upload other files...Not sure why this has stopped working....

---

edit:
in case it helps, I've added my code to upload files (using the same ftp settings). this works fine - how can I modify it to upload the Image?

```
uploadfile:
FileStream file = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);
                int length = 1024;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                int bytesRead = 0;

                totalToUpload = file.Length;
                try
                {
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);
                        ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        totalReadBytesCount += bytesRead;
                        var progress = totalReadBytesCount * 100.0 / totalToUpload;
                        backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress((int)progress);
                    }
                    while (bytesRead != 0);
                    file.Close();
```

Comment: Has something changed on the server you're uploading to? Can you upload to another FTP server successfully? It could be that the server is only accepting a limited amount of data per call, you should really be looping until there is nothing left to upload.

Comment: I'm not aware of any changes on the server...
How would I in-cooperate a loop into the above code? I originally looked to upload the image via ftp stream but I could not find any code that would it - which is why I did it via the save method?

Comment: It appears you can't loop. I was expecting `Image.Save(stream,...)` to return the number of bytes written, but it doesn't. I take it there are no exceptions raised.

Comment: Image codecs tend to count on being able to seek in the stream they read/write.  I know it is a problem for reading, it may well be a problem for writing as well.  The NetworkStream you get from GetRequestStream has CanSeek = false.  So a workaround would be to save to a file or a MemoryStream first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upload it using streams:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] imgBytes = ms.ToArray();

ftpstream.Write(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.Length); 
ftpstream.Close();
```

You can also try to loop the writing